# Can I uninstall & replace Firefox with another browser of my choice?

Tags: installation, uninstall, browser

I don't like the Firefox Web browser, and I prefer to use something else.

How can I remove it and use a browser of my choice?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There can be some packages that depend on (or recommend) a browser, in the form of a virtual package (`firefox` provides the virtual packages `www-browser`, `iceweasel` and `gnome-www-browser`) or through an alternative (some package depends on `firefox | chromium-browser`).

To solve your problem you can use `aptitude` that provides more choices to as to proceed. The package `aptitude` is not installed by default, so you need to install it

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

then you can do

```
aptitude --simulate remove firefox
```

and see what it suggests. This is what it says on my system

```
enzotib@laptop:$ aptitude --simulate remove firefox
The following packages will be REMOVED:  
  firefox 
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 30.6 MB will be freed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  icedtea-plugin: Depends: firefox (>= 4.0~b7) but it is not going to be installed. or
                           chromium-browser but it is not going to be installed. or
                           epiphany-browser but it is not going to be installed. or
                           midori but it is not going to be installed.
  firefox-globalmenu: Depends: firefox (= 5.0+build1+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.11.04.2) but it is not going to be installed.
  firefox-gnome-support: Depends: firefox but it is not going to be installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Remove the following packages:                                                             
1)      firefox-globalmenu                                                                       
2)      firefox-gnome-support                                                                    
3)      icedtea-plugin                                                                           
4)      icedtea6-plugin                                                                          

      Leave the following dependencies unresolved:                                               
5)      totem-mozilla recommends epiphany-browser | www-browser                                  
6)      ubuntu-desktop recommends firefox                                                        
7)      ubuntu-desktop recommends firefox-gnome-support                                          
8)      moonlight-plugin-mozilla recommends firefox | abrowser | iceweasel | xulrunner-1.9.2     
9)      ubuntu-restricted-addons recommends icedtea6-plugin                                      
10)     xul-ext-ubufox recommends firefox (>= 4.0~b6) | abrowser (>= 4.0~b6)                     
11)     mozilla-libreoffice recommends iceweasel | firefox | iceape-browser | konqueror-nsplugins


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

This way you can see removing firefox what packages breaks. If you choose `n`, another possible solution is suggested, ans so on.

When you have a best understanding of the problem, and you have selected your way, run `aptitude` without the `--simulate` option.

Answer (score 4):

Your original (unedited) question mentioned Firefox crashing constantly.  You could try installing the latest stable release via PPA:

https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/firefox-stable

Comment: or in synaptic reinstalling it

Answer (score 2):

I personally use Firefox but I have also installed another browser for trouble shooting purposes it is always a good ideal to have more than one browser .

But if you want to  uninstall Firefox open a terminal: `sudo apt-get autoremove firefox`

- If you want Chromium browser: `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`

Or install what ever  Web Browser you want to use. At which point you would then remove Firefox  which should make the browser you installed the default one.

Comment: Also ´sudo apt-get autoremove --purge firefox´

Answer (score 1):

There is no sane way. I did just `sudo apt-get --reinstall install firefox`. You also might try maybe setting alternative default browser with "Preferred applications" before trying to remove firefox.

Answer (score -3):

I was having this trouble myself.  Uninstall sun-java first then uninstall firefox and chromium/epiphany.