# How to remove apt browsers and use Flatpak browser

Tags: apt, firefox, flatpak

Similar to this question [Why does removing Firefox install another browser?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11934/why-does-removing-firefox-install-another-browser) when I try to remove Firefox installed via apt, apt tries to install Chromium as an alternative as I have dependencies that require a browser to be installed.

I'm using Firefox flatpak from flathub and have set this to default in Gnome-settings and xdg:

```bash
$ xdg-settings get default-web-browser
org.mozilla.firefox.desktop
```

How do I set the Flatpak Firefox to satisfy the apt browser requirement?

Comment: I'm having a different, but possibly related problem; I haven't figured out quite what's going on yet, but one thing I noticed is that there are (why? I don't know yet) several different firefox-related .desktop files in various places.  The launcher was for some reason pointing to the wrong one and that was messing up the the default setting (not sure how/why yet).
So maybe just to rule it out, search and make sure you don't have more than one .desktop, and that you are pointing to the right one?

Comment: This page has some detailed info about where, and in what order, flatpak looks for .desktop files.  Might be helpful: https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/conventions.html